# I need API URL of GMapProviders.GoogleMap

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

I use the gmap.net library for my WinForms application and connection through the proxy.

Here is the code:

```
        mapCtrl.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
        GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerOnly;
        GMap.NET.MapProviders.GMapProvider.WebProxy =
        System.Net.WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        GMap.NET.MapProviders.GMapProvider.WebProxy.Credentials =
        System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

The problem is that the information security department of my company is blocking these connections and as result, the maps tiles don't load. They ask me to give them the API URL for entering it into the white list.
Somebody knows which URL uses Gmap.net for GMapProviders.GoogleMap?

Comment: Use a tool like WireShark or Fiddler on your local machine and see what URLs the application tries to access over the network.

Comment: Fiddler helped me. Put your comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Martin Costello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064169/martin-costello)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68712135/i-need-api-url-of-gmapproviders-googlemap/73029102#comment121433855_68712135)

> Use a tool like WireShark or Fiddler on your local machine and see what URLs the application tries to access over the network.

Using Fiddler helped me.